# How to call C/C++ binaries (ported on linux server) from Android application

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, binaries

I have developed C/C++ binaries and I have android app. I have ported binaries on linux base server and now I would like to use this binaries in my android app. Can i call this binaries from my app? Is it possible, please excuse me as I don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will find a nice tutorial to implement C code into your Android Project:

[JNI tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, but I think he need to understand about JNI complexity from the bottom to implement his own C code.

Comment: Thanks for the link but i have query for this, please don't take me wrong if my question looks stupid as I am newbie for this. I have my C code already uploaded on the server ok. Now why i need to create JNI for my android project. Do i need to include the binaries in my android app? This is like web service but I have C code instead of web service, my binaries will return me the data in text only.